# Search data associated with changing username

Tags: mongodb

In a hypothetical project I am working on there are users who can play games and set highscores, the users display name can change at any time but duplicates are not allowed. I plan on using MongoDB as it seems to support more rapid development than SQL alternatives. There are many types of games a user can play, all which have some kind of score which will need to be stored in the database. The scores will then need to be queried for their score so a high scores list can be built. Coming from SQL I could do something like this:

`+------+-----------+ 
 |UserID|DisplayName| 
 +------------------+ 
 |883   |John02     | 
 |2321  |James55    | 
 |22    |Sam        | 
 |943   |Joe        | 
 +------+-----------+
 +------+------+-----+
 |GameID|UserID|Score|
 +-------------------+
 |1     |883   |9001 |
 |3     |2321  |2    |
 |2     |22    |1337 |
 |2     |943   |998  |
 +------+------+-----+`

What is something equivalent for Mongo? Am I thinking of this too much like a relational database?

Comment: Is a GameId referring to a particular game, so you are storing, for each player and game, their highest score? You aren't storing every score the player gets in a particular game, just the highest score they've ever gotten in that game?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two collections namely Users , Games.

note: In mongodb, tables are called as collections. then, user id will be generated automatically in mongodb. you don't need specific field for user id.

where Games belongs to User. and User has_many Games. below is code snippet using ruby on rails.

```
class User 
...
field :name
has_many :games
end

class Games
...
field :score
belongs_to :User
end
```

When you have this kind of architecture, you can query your database to get games associated with user like below

usr = User.where(name: "some name")
usr.games.all => return all games asssociated with particular user

any doubt, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on kind of query you are going to frequently making . For example in case all your query is associated to user , like show all the game played by a user you can keep the schema like this, user collection will be have document like this , where Games is embedded sub document.

```
               {
                   Id : "",
                   Name : "Test Name",
                   Games : [{ Id : 1 , Score : 1234 } , { Id : 2 , Score : 3456}]
               }
```

But the problem with this schema is that now if you want to search for certain game top scorer it is going to be very tricky , but we can duplicate the data in another collection called Game

```
              {
                  Id : 123,
                  Scores : [{ User : "Test" ,  Score : 5678} , { User : "Hello" , Score : 3456                      }],Top Scorer : [{}]

              }
```